# Split list by criterion

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of numbers and I want to split this list into two sublists: one for odd numbers and another one for evens.

```
evens, odds = [], []
for e in numbers:
    if e % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(e)
    else:
        odds.append(e)
```

I wonder if there is a one-liner for this problem while keeping the same order of complexity.

I tried using `itertools.groupby` but the list needs to be ordered first so I'd be achieving a `O(2n)` rather than `O(n)`:

```
def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

lst = sorted(lst, key=is_even)
grouper = itertools.groupby(lst, key=is_even)
lst1, lst2 = [list(v) for k, v in grouper]
```

Comment: As a side note, `O(2n)` and `O(n)` have the same magnitude and most of the time can be treated as equal.

Comment: O(2n) is the same as O(n), just saying...

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah I know, but it's still twice as slow, it just bothers me and I'd rather do it as efficient as possible

Comment: And by the way, while we are at it, your `groupby` solution is not `O(2n)`. Since `sorted` is using quicksort the complexity of your second solution is (on average) `O(nlogn + n)`.

Comment: @DeepSpace true that I really didn't stop to think what sorting algorithm was being used, my point was that it added extra level of complexity that the first loop doesn't introduce

Comment: @DeepSpace quicksort -> timsort. And by the way, the first solution is not even close to O(n) as the `append` might re-allocate the lists, leading to O(n^2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using the ternary operator prior to append:

```
evens, odds = [], []
for e in numbers:
    (odds if e % 2 else evens).append(e)
```

Of course you could do this inside a list comprehension, but it's not Pythonic to use a comprehension for it's side-effects because you create a potentially large unwanted list of `None` values. You could instead use the [itertools consume recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) if you want to take that route.

Comment: Not the easiest to read, but I think that this answer fit the most as it's O(n).

Comment: can you elaborate on how to use `consume` for this question?

Comment: @dabadaba would be like `consume((odds if e % 2 else evens).append(e) for e in numbers)`

Comment: @dabadaba In fact for your case you could use `collections.deque(((odds if e % 2 else evens).append(e) for e in numbers), maxlen=0)`

Comment: that is pretty nice! i'll try to remember that recipe...

Answer (score 3):

You *could* abuse list comprehension, but please **don't** do that in production code.

```
nums = range(6)
odds = []
evens = []
[odds.append(num) if num % 2 == 1 else evens.append(num) for num in nums]
print(odds, evens)
# [1, 3, 5] [2, 4]
```

Comment: This is a bad way of using list comprehension

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah I saw it before posting, but I wouldn't recommend it in any case.